# How to read large file from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, out-of-memory

I tried to read file (650 megabytes) from SQL Server:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
{
   if (reader.Read())
   {
       using (var dbStream = reader.GetStream(0))
       {
          if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
          {
              stream.Position = 0;
              dbStream.CopyTo(stream, 256);
           }

           dbStream.Close();
         }
       }

       reader.Close();
    }
```

But I got `OutOfMemoryException` on `CopyTo()`.

With small files, this code snippet works fine. How can I handle large file?

Comment: Hmmm....would have thought that would have worked even in x86

Comment: That's not SQL Server, that's C#.

Comment: @Larnu Okey, tags edited

Comment: what are you going to do with that stream data in memory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821880/how-to-create-copy-of-file-using-streamreader-and-streamwriter

Comment: What is the concrete type of `stream`? If it's `MemoryStream` then that's your problem...

Comment: @Albert in this case i'll want to save stream in file.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yeah `var stream = new MemoreStream();` What is not right with it?

Comment: Well, guess where the appropriately-named `MemoryStream` keeps all its data?

Comment: @MatthewWatson But i have a lot of free memory in moment when exception fired. So alternative way it is M_Idrees solution use FileStream to hold large file?

Comment: Yeah you can write it to a file stream, but you don't have to hand-roll the loop - you can use `Stream.CopyTo()` like you are already doing, but just change `MemoryStream` to `FileStream`. Note that you're possibly running out of large heap space due to memory fragmentation.

Comment: [This  article about memory fragmentation](https://www.wintellect.com/hey-who-stole-all-my-memory/) may be of interest.

Comment: Also, don't use a buffer so small. The default is  `81920` bytes (and it could be small anyway).

Comment: @MatthewWatson I change `MemoryStream` to `FileStream` and its works fast and fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read and write data to some temp file in small chunks. You can see example on [MSDN - Retrieving Binary Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-binary-data).

```
//Column Index in the result set
const int colIdx = 0;

// Writes the BLOB to a file (*.bmp).  
FileStream stream;                            
// Streams the BLOB to the FileStream object.  
BinaryWriter writer;                          

// Size of the BLOB buffer.  
int bufferSize = 100;                     
// The BLOB byte[] buffer to be filled by GetBytes.  
byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize];    
// The bytes returned from GetBytes.  
long retval;                              
// The starting position in the BLOB output.  
long startIndex = 0;                      

// Open the connection and read data into the DataReader.  
connection.Open();  
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);  

while (reader.Read())  
{  

  // Create a file to hold the output.  
  stream = new FileStream(  
    "some-physical-file-name-to-dump-data.bmp", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);  
  writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);  

  // Reset the starting byte for the new BLOB.  
  startIndex = 0;  

  // Read bytes into outByte[] and retain the number of bytes returned.  
  retval = reader.GetBytes(colIdx, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);  

  // Continue while there are bytes beyond the size of the buffer.  
  while (retval == bufferSize)  
  {  
    writer.Write(outByte);  
    writer.Flush();  

    // Reposition start index to end of last buffer and fill buffer.  
    startIndex += bufferSize;  
    retval = reader.GetBytes(colIdx, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);  
  }  

  // Write the remaining buffer.  
  writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval);  
  writer.Flush();  

  // Close the output file.  
  writer.Close();  
  stream.Close();  
}  

// Close the reader and the connection.  
reader.Close();  
connection.Close();
```

Make sure you are using `SqlDataReader` with `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`, note this line in above code snippet.

```
 SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
```

More information on `CommandBehavior` enum can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandbehavior?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_CommandBehavior_SequentialAccess).

**EDIT:**

Let me clarify myself. I agreed with @MickyD, cause of the problem is not whether you are using `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` or not, but reading the large file at-once.

I emphasized on this because it is commonly missed by developers, they tend to read files in chunks but without setting `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` they will encounter other problems. Although it is already posted with original question, but highlighted in my answer to give point to any new comers.

Comment: [`Stream.CopyTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netframework-4.7.2) already copies in chunks (in the OP's code it's copying in chunks of only 256 bytes, which seems too small...)

Comment: I am confused. @MatthewWatson said that `CopyTo()` is waht i need. But @M_Idress said that i gona rewrite code. WHo is right?

Comment: @MatthewWatson i tried to use 4096 instead 256 bytes but got same error

Comment: CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess is important factor here.  Rather than loading the entire row, SequentialAccess enables the DataReader to load data as a stream.

Comment: But the OP is already using `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`

Comment: As per the documentation on MSDN mentioned in link... You can use the GetBytes or GetChars method to specify a byte location to start the read operation, and a limited buffer size for the data being returned...

Comment: OP is already performing `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` and his buffer is tiny.  They are **not** the cause of the issue

Answer (score 0):

> @MatthewWatson yeah var stream = new MemoreStream(); What is not right with it? – Kliver Max 15 hours ago

Your problem is not whether or not you are using:

```
`command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)`
```

...which you are as we can see; or that your stream copy buffer size is too big (it's actually tiny) but rather that you are using `MemoryStream` as you indicated in the comments above.  More than likely you are loading in the 650MB file **twice**, **once from SQL** and another to be stored in the **MemoryStream** thus leading to your **OutOfMemoryException**.

Though the solution is to instead write to a file stream, the cause of the problem wasn't highlighted in the accepted answer.   Unless you know the cause of a problem, you won't learn to avoid such issues in the future.